# Reduce run-time in C++

Tags: c++, optimization

Recently, CodeVita Season 9 is running all over the world which is organized by TCS. There's one problem statement given below.

**Problem Description :**

Given an array of integers A, and an integer K find number of happy elements.

Element X is happy if there exists at least 1 element whose difference is less than K i.e. an element X is happy, if there is another element in the range [X-K, X+K] other than X itself.

**Constraints**

1 <= N <= 10^5

0 <= K <= 10^5

0 <= A[i] <= 10^9

**Time Limit**

1

According to this, I've done my code with C++. Here's the code,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int siz, x;
    cin>>siz;
    cin>>x;
    if(siz>= 1 && siz<= pow(10, 5) && x>=0 && x<= pow(10, 5)){
        int a[siz];
        for(int i=0; i<siz; i++){
            cin>>a[i];
            if(a[i]>=0 && a[i]<= pow(10, 9))
                continue;
            else
                break;
        }
        int cnt, op = 0, i = 0;
        while(i<siz){
            cnt = 0;
            int dif1 = a[i] - x;
            int dif2 = a[i] + x;
            for(int j=0; j<siz; j++){
                if(a[j]>= dif1 && a[j] <= dif2){
                    if(a[j] != a[i])
                        cnt=1;
                }
            }
            if(cnt == 1)
                ++op;
            i++;
        }
        cout<<op;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It shows the same output as wanted but on CodeVita Plateform, they're not accepting this code showing "Time Limit Exceeds".
Now, I don't know how to make this code the way it doesn't exceeds the time limit.
Seeking support from community.

Comment: If its a currently a part of some competition, its better you try and solve it yourself. It will be better if you ask for what went wrong after the competition.

Comment: `pow(10, 5)` and `pow(10, 9)` are potentially expensive. A  good compiler will notice the values never change and replace them with a constant, but...

Comment: `int a[siz];` is not legal in Standard C++. One of the reasons for this is user-sized variable length arrays are one stop shopping for all your stack overflow needs.

Comment: You have a portion of code that is O(N-squared). Often this is the kiss of death in an online judge question with a tight time limit. Concentrate your efforts on finding patterns you can use to reduce the amount of work that must be performed.

Comment: Here's a hint.  Keep a running hash table of type `std::map<int, int>` that represents the number of occurrences of any integer. The first element in the map is the lower bound, the second element in the map is the upper bound.  As you scan the array, remove elements `a[i-K]` from the map and add element `a[i+K]` to the map.

Answer (score 1):

you could take advantage of very efficient tools of standard library.
If you store your value in a std::vector, you can use the std::sort to have the values sorted.
Then iterate on the vector looking the difference between two consecutive elements.

It will be more efficient because standard library algorythms are efficient. Sorting may be as low as O(n log n) on average, and final search is O(n)

Your searching loop is O(n2), which is much worse.